LayerZero secure _lzReceive'al (?)
guys!
Wondering whether the usage of _getPeerOrRevert secures the lzReceive function on its own, or is there still a need to verify the origin and executor addresses?
For instance, if I'm already using if (_getPeerOrRevert(_origin.srcEid) != _origin.sender) revert OnlyPeer(_origin.srcEid, _origin.sender); which Ensure(s) that the sender matches the expected peer for the source endpoint. (https://docs.layerzero.network/v2/developers/evm/developer-overview#oapp-execution), does that mean that I don't need to mandatorily verify the origin and executor addresses in my overriden _lzReceive child function?
Or do I have to verify that the origin is one of the system's addresses on the other chains too? E.g. like require(keccak256(_srcAddress) == keccak256(trustedRemoteLookup[_srcChainId]); or require(keccak256(origin) == keccak256(trustedRemoteLookup[_srcChainId]);.
